# How to find the number of non-zeros in an array in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to find the number of zeros in the custom loss function for Keras.

```
def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
```

Where this loss function is inputted here:

```
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss=root_mean_squared_error,
              metrics=[metrics.mse, root_mean_squared_error])
```

I am trying to find the number of non-zero values in the array `y_true` and divide my number by this value.

How can I find the number of non-zero elements in `y_true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`tf.count_nonzero`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/count_nonzero) API via Keras backend.

```
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return y_pred / K.cast(K.tf.count_nonzero(y_true), K.tf.float32)

y_t = K.placeholder((1,2))
y_p = K.placeholder((1,2))

loss = custom_loss(y_t, y_p)

print(K.get_session().run(loss, {y_t: np.array([[1,1]]), y_p: np.array([[2,4]])}))
```

The result is

```
[[1. 2.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the boolean condition `y_true != 0` with the NumPy array :

```
z = np.array( y_true != 0 )
# Check the shape of z array.
print( z.shape )
count = z.shape[ 0 ]
```

**Here, count should be the number of elements for which the `y_true != 0` condition is true.**

Comment: This would work. However, y_true and y_pred are not numpy arrays. They are keras arrays